# how can i foreach data from two tables laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

```
public function queries($companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)
{
    $data = [];
    $details = DiraQuestion::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
    $detailsAns = DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();

    foreach($details as $key => $detailsValue)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->intent, $data))
        {
        $data[$detailsValue->intent] = [];
        }

        if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->reply, $data[$detailsValue->intent]))
        {
            $data[$detailsValue->intent]['answer'][$detailsValue->reply] = $detailsValue->id;
        }

        if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->queries, $data[$detailsValue->intent]))
        {
            $data[$detailsValue->intent]['question'][$detailsValue->queries] = $detailsValue->id;
        }
    }

    ksort($data);
    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.queries', compact('data','entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
}
```

I have written a code to view data but I'm having some problems.

From the code I wrote it's viewing the data from one table which is the `$details`.
But I also wanna view the data from the `$detailsAns`.

How can I do that? also can I `foreach` two data from that two tables?

Comment: If `DiraQuestion` and `DiraResponses` are related, use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) to load the data so you could iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

The first way use normal `for` instead of a `foreach`,

**For Exmple:**

```
public function test(){
    $data = [];
    $details = ["details0", "details1", "details2", "details3", "details4", "details5", "details6", "details7"];
    $detailsAns = ["details0Ans", "details1Ans", "details2Ans", "details3Ans", "details4Ans", "details5Ans", "details6Ans", "details7Ans"];


    for ($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($details) || $i < sizeof($detailsAns) ;$i++) {
        echo $details[$i];
        echo $detailsAns[$i];
    }
}
```

Second way use `MultipleIterator::attachIterator`

Not the most efficient, but a demonstration of SPL's multipleIterator

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($a));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($b));

$newArray = array();
foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    list($value1, $value2) = $value;
    echo $value1 , '-' , $value2 , PHP_EOL;
}
```

```html
public function queries($companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)
{
  $data = [];
  $details = DiraQuestion::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
  $detailsAns = DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();

  $mi = new MultipleIterator();
  $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($details));
  $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($detailsAns));
  foreach($mi as $value ) {

    list($detailsValue, $detailAnsValue) = $value;
    if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->intent, $data))
    {
      $data[$detailsValue->intent] = [];
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->reply, $data[$detailsValue->intent]))
    {
      $data[$detailsValue->intent]['answer'][$detailsValue->reply] = $detailsValue->id;
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($detailsValue->queries, $data[$detailsValue->intent]))
    {
      $data[$detailsValue->intent]['question'][$detailsValue->queries] = $detailsValue->id;
    }
  }

  ksort($data);
  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.queries', compact('data','entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
}
```

**Example:**

```
public function test(){
    $data = [];
    $details = ["details0", "details1", "details2", "details3", "details4", "details5", "details6", "details7"];
    $detailsAns = ["details0Ans", "details1Ans", "details2Ans", "details3Ans", "details4Ans", "details5Ans", "details6Ans", "details7Ans"];

    $mi = new MultipleIterator();
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($details));
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($detailsAns));
    foreach($mi as $value ) {

        list($detailsValue, $detailAnsValue) = $value;
        echo($detailsValue);
        echo($detailAnsValue);
    }
}
//output: details0details0Ansdetails1details1Ansdetails2details2Ansdetails3details3Ansdetails4details4Ansdetails5details5Ansdetails6details6Ansdetails7details7Ans
```

Comment: can you show me an example for the first for method? Also i tried your second method and im not getting any data back

Comment: oh hmm i think maybe you didnt get what i asked, what i want to do is to get the data from the database based on 3 values then return data from 2 tables

Comment: ok I think now I find what you want, you want to access two array in one loop? or Iterate on two array in one loop? if second one use iterator else use 'normal for' in 'normal for' we have index of iterator. but if these are not whats you want please explain more. and edit your question with some more exmaple

Comment: yes correct to access two array in one loop. so as you can see i can return the data from foreach for $details but now i want to return data for $detailsAns also. how can i do that?

Comment: You can access the two array now you can get each index of $detailsAns every time you wan't but in your example only iterate on one array.in the 'normal for loop' you have a counter and with that counter you can access to each three array you have.